# Prevent cookie from being sent to server

Tags: javascript, iframe, cookies, web

I am writing an application where most of the state is stored on the client side. The state is somewhat *private information*, so I would like to *keep it on the client side*. There are some strict policies that forbid this information ever reaching my server. Until now I used `localStorage` and it was a perfect solution.

Unfortunately it turns out Safari has some issues with localStorages and iframes ([1](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=172501), [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsmentors/Jby_5Tt47SI), [3](https://github.com/bemson/subetha-bridge/issues/2)). If I use cookies the browser will send them to the server which is not acceptable. All the stored data is managed using javascript, no http Set-Cookie header is used.

The basic usecase is the following: The application has a "master" page in domain A, on which the user can change his settings, and there is a page in an other domain (B), which has an iframe pointing to some special page in domain A, and uses postMessage and onmessage to exchange some information. The master page of domain A and the iframe embedded in domain B must share some storage to operate.

Any ides on this?

**EDIT 1**

One idea is the following: Ask the user for a password in the iframe and on the "master" page too, and use that password to encrypt the private information. The encrypted private info can be stored in cookies, as my server doesn't have the users password. This is the best solution so far, but is uncomfortable for the users.

Comment: why don't you delete all the cookies in the browser via javascript cookies libraries. By this you add / edit / delete cookies.

Comment: Why is it a problem if cookie is sent to the server? That's its job, to be sent to the server.

Comment: There may be something useful here (https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/) which talks about combining cross-document messaging and localStorage in order to share data across domains.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki I want them to persist data.

Comment: @Mjh I wish to store private information. Yes, I want to misuse cookies. If safari did the job right, I'd use localstorage.

Comment: Ok, encrypt the cookie on the client side and don't share the key with your server. That way you can misuse cookies, but have no clue what's in them on the serverside. Would that help?

Comment: @Mjh but for that he'll have to keep the key some way... so he'll need to store the key in a cookie, too, and this is useless.

Comment: @Al.G. - you don't have to store the key. You can use a method that comes up with the same symmetric key, using unique information proprietary to every browser. That way keys will be different per every user, and won't be shared with the server. To obtain this unique, computed key, one can use information in `window.navigator`. Since cookies are being "misused", and since the server shouldn't know this sensitive information, I think that the approach with cookies encrypted at client side is just fine for the use case.

Comment: @Mjh Encryption is fine, but are you sure that information in window.navigator is unique for every user? I don't see any info in there which is not predictable. If there was an at least 16 bytes long random generated machine id in there, different for each origin, that would be pretty good.

Comment: @TamasHegedus - it was an example of what can be used to come up with a key that you can use for encryption. Your problem is specific and you're using an unorthodox solution. `window.navigator` isn't the same for everyone, but can be. What *could* be the solution is this: you're probably delivering some sort of `user_id` if you require your users to be logged on. You can use some information in `window.navigator`, a part of information about the user coming from server and then together that can form a hash which you can use for encryption key. Would that help?

Comment: @Mjh I am concerned about the predictability of that key. The server side is going to know the `user_id` and the encrypted data too, so it could still guess the encryption keys because they are derived from a known set of navigator values. Previously I used a similar technique, that consisted of generating a key on the client side using `crypto.getRandomValues` and storing it in the `localStorage`. But guess what, Safari still does not like to share the `localStorage` between a tab and an iframe of the same origin :(.

Comment: @Mjh So I like the concept, but in that case I have to be sure about I use proper keys for encryption. For example some unpredictable hardware keys would be great, but I don't know about such values being exposed by the browser

Comment: You're right, those keys *could* be predictable. However, is there really some man in the middle on the communication line between your server and user's browser? I'm unsure what you're trying to avoid, potential eaves dropper or you're trying to prevent yourself from reading someone's information?

Comment: @Mjh Right, I should've made that clear at the beginning. I want to prevent myself from accessing the data to meet some strict compliance requirements.

Comment: Hash the user's password and username, have that as a key? You should never have access to plaintext version of people's password anyway, and that's the common denominator of what you don't know - their password. You can salt, hash it and use that as encryption key.

Comment: I don't want them to enter credentials multiple times (once for the tab, once for the inner iframe). But if there is no better solution, maybe thats the way we should go.

Comment: Do not try to develop a procedure to create keys. Key generation and encryption are supported natively in all browsers with  WebCryptographiApi. Also the key can be stored in storage in a secure way. the user or the developer may use keys but not see the content

Comment: For the cross domain storage function take a look at https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage. It works with localStorage, not cookies, but the tecnique is the same. ¿could you use  an indexedDB with a central domain communicating the info to the page through an iframe?

Comment: @pedrofb - did you read anything in the comments? Due to the potential issues, no localStorage, sessionStorage or any other mechanism other than cookies is to be used.

Comment: I suggested use WebCryptographiApi to generate encryption keys and share it with indexedDB instead of localStorage but  @Mjh, you are right, if Safari blocks iframe cross domain communication, it can not be used. 
At least in this browser

Comment: @pedrofb - if the limitation for storage weren't cookies, then yes, you are 100% right with your suggestion *where* to store the key. However, key can be extrapolated from combination of data that only client knows (such as their password, which can be transformed by hashing / encoding on client side to produce a symmetric key). That way, no key is ever stored anywhere, is unique to each user, and can be used for client side cookie encryption.

Comment: it should consider that a password change will eventually invalidate the key, needing to decrypt and encrypt again

Comment: Ok guys, as I read through this conversation what I see is that now we are talking more about cryptography than about cookies. Seriously, I really appreciate your help, but I would like to stop the conversation about cryptography, as it leads to the same question as the original, but now with encryption keys instead of actual data.

Comment: I researched a little, and seems there is no workaround to allow iframe access cookies&localStorage if main page is located in different domain. Only enabling the Safari preference "Cookies and website data: Allow from websites I visit". I have tested it, and works properly. So I think the second part of your issue can not be done at this time

Comment: @pedrofb: I've done some research myself too, and got the same result. It's sad that we cannot workaround this. For me the solution will most probably be to trust and involve domain B in data storage.

Comment: you can use webSQL in safari and indexedDB everywhere instead of localStorage or cookies

Comment: @dandavis Thanks, great idea, but it seems safaris webSQL doesnt work inside cross origin iframes. It throws `SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: IDBFactory.open() called in an invalid security context`

Answer (score 3):

According to [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/585663/Communication-with-Cross-Domain-IFrame-A-Cross-Bro) You can use

```
window.parent.postMessage("Hello From IFrame", "*");
```

in combination with an event listener in the parent frame

```
window.addEventListener ("message", OnMessage, false);
```

to cross-domain communicate from the child frame to the parent.

You can then use local storage in the parent frame to keep your shared information as before.

Comment: My hopes were that I can accomplish my goals without exposing any data to the parent frame, only using the embedded iframes origin to store all the data. Unfortunately it seems that there is no workaround, so I will have to involve the parent frame. Not exactly in the same way as you suggest, I find it easier to  to use the hash fragment of the url of the iframe.

Comment: Oh and I see you provided an example for the opposite direction, but the code for sending data into the iframe would be pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session storage instead if local storage doesn't work well, since session storage is not being sent to server.

But the **limitation** of using session storage is you will not be able to share data between tabs on same domain, inside a single tab it will work fine.

Comment: The sessionStorage is even more limited than localStorage. Unfortunately the main usecase is to share data between tabs, more specifically between a tab and an iframe in another tab. And whats more, the tabs are not necessarily open at the same time, so sadly sessionStorage will not work at all for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure, but perhaps you are looking for a solution that:

1. No asking for password for encrypting private data
2. Permanent password for each user to encrypt the private data (next time user comes back, still using the same password)

How about using the user's login password to encrypt the data?

Or generate a token from server and store in client side as well. From server when send back the data to client, check the token and encrypt the data based on the token. Try to build multiple type of token, each type different kind of encryption.

**Other solution**

Using the secure cookie + http strict transportation. You don't need to change anything, just implement them based on your back-end. You can read more from here: 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are suggesting to keep encryption keys in cookies, so they are sent to the server, but keep the encrypted content on the client side. I am afraid this doesnt solve the initial problem: how will the content get into the Iframe from the other (same origin) browser tab? (and this tab is most probably closed before the page with the iframe gets opened)

Comment: Any time any change from the client, you push to the server a modification time flag. In the iframe (or create a new iframe) use web socket or ajax to check that flag. If need to update the content then reload the iframe to get the latest content from cookies. Then postMessage back to your original iframe (if create new iframe for checking flag).